# session times out very quickly on production server with asp.net core 2.2 razor pages app with auth

Tags: authentication, session, asp.net-core, razor-pages

Hoping someone can help maybe please?

I have a web app created using ASP.Net Core 2.2 Razor pages.

When the project was created the Auth was selected as part of the project creation.

When published to production, and when logged in, the session sometimes only lasts seconds before effectively dying and logging you out.

It is on shared hosting but has a dedicated app pool (which i read somewhere it would maybe need).

I have tried both of the following in web.config of the published app but makes no difference (both were found in various place in Google searches).

```
<system.web>
    <sessionState timeout="300" mode="InProc" />
</system.web>
```

And also

```
  <system.web>
    <sessionState mode="StateServer" stateConnectionString="tcpip=loopback:42424" cookieless="false" timeout="300" />
  </system.web>
```

Any information greatly appreciated.

Comment: Within seconds? Sounds unlikely unless the other apps on the shared hosts run on same app pool and use so many resources that they force IIS to restart the app pool. What do you use for data protection persistency (to persist the encryption key for cookies/sessions)? If you don't persist the cryptographical keys, all sessions become invalidated when the application restarts, since a new key will be generated on every restart

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  The website is on shared hosting as I say and it has (according to the hosting control panel) a dedicated app pool although I don't seem to be able to get any kind of access to it - a restriction of the hosting.  Am I wrong to think that if it all works as it should in Development environment (localhost) but not love on Production the issue lies on the shared server end potentially?

Comment: Maybe your app crashing too. But thats just a side-issue. As said in the comment, you have to presist the encryption keys, so when the application restarts, it can load the previously generated keys for encryption and decryption. Without it, all sessions become invalid when app restarts. IIS usually has idle time of 5 to 15 minutes (after in which on activity happens the AppPool will be shut down)